# c# scriptmanager script gets called with other script

Tags: c#, asp.net

### RESOLVED!

### Used OnClientClick="window.parent.close()" on the asp:button instead of the close window script, I was overcomplicating it.

I've got the two scripts below on a aspx page. But when the "closeWindow" one get's called by a asp:button, it shows the "Email Sent" message instead but does close the window after.

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Close Window" id="closewindowbutton" onclick="closewindowbutton_Click" class="btn"  />
</asp:Content>

protected void closewindowbutton_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            Page page = HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler as Page;
            if (page != null && !page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered("closeWindow"))
            {
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(page, typeof(Page), "closeWindow", "window.close();", true);
                // ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "closeWindow", "window.close();", true);
            }
        }

        public static void ShowAlert(string message)
        {
            string cleanMessage = message.Replace("'", "\'");
            Page page = HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler as Page;
            string script = string.Format("alert('{0}');", cleanMessage);
            if (page != null && !page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered("alert"))
            {
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(page, typeof(Page), "alert", script, true);
            }
            return;
        }


<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
```

on page load it show's the "email sent" message:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
  ShowAlert("Email Sent!");
}
```

Comment: I could not reproduce, could you show more of your code? Are you using a single page or all .aspx pages are part of Master?

Comment: Added some more code above, they are part of a Master

Comment: If you dont mind me asking, why do you call ShowAlert on Page_Load? You see, when you click the button it will create a post-back, and on every post-back Page_Load method is triggerd causing ShowAlert("Email Sent!"); to be called! Now if you add another button and click it, i bet you ShowAlert("Email Sent!");
 will be called again. You should remove ShowAlert("Email Sent!");
 from Page_Load, but tell me why its there so we can find an alternative?

Comment: It sends an email (i've removed the send mail code) when the page it loaded, and then needs to show a "Email sent" message automatically, but I don't understand why both scripts are called together, do I need seperate scriptmanagers for each script?

Comment: I just updated my answer below... see if that helps!